# C# Entity Framework 6 Context Object Database First with existing DbConnection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am new to Entity Framework and i don't know how to solve this problem.

I got an existing System.Data.Common.DbConnection with which i have to initialize the Context-Object in a Database First Scenario. I have tried this constructor

```
public DbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, DbCompiledModel model, bool contextOwnsConnection),
```

but it looks like its only for Code First. Is it possible to use an existing DbConnection with Database First?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the DbConnection was not an Entity Connection and this means the Connection works as Code First.

It works if i create a EntityConnection with the DbConnection and create the right Workspace and then use the Entity Connection with this contructor:

```
public DbContext(DbConnection connection, bool contextOwnsAndDisposesTheConnection)
```